# SAPUI5 - List items, view model sorting issue

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am doing multiple OData entity set reads and pushing the results into a view model.

The view model gets all the results from **QuestionSet** and on success then gets several other properties from **CategorySet**.

What I want to do in my *EditSurvey* view, is to load all data from my view model (`view>/Questions`) and sort the results by `CategoryDesc` (pushed in from **CategorySet**).

It looks like the *EditSurvey* view is trying to load the model before the results of **CategorySet** are pushed into the view model.

Does anyone know how I can sort this?

#### EditSurvey.view.xml

```
<List
  noDataText="{i18n>noQuestions}"
  items="{
    path: 'view>/Questions',
    sorter: {
      path: 'CategoryDesc',
      descending: false,
      group: true
    }
  }"
  mode="SingleSelectMaster"
  selectionChange="onQuestionSelect"
>
```

#### EditSurvey.controller.js

```
onInit: function() {
  var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
  oRouter.getRoute("EditSurvey").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
  // Intialise view model
  var oModel = new JSONModel({
    SurveyName: "",
    SurveyDesc: "",
    ReportingFrom: "",
    Questions: [{ }]
  });
  // Set view model
  this.getView().setModel(oModel, "view");
},

_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
  // Get URL parameters passed from Main Page.
  var oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
  // Get view model
  var self = this;
  var view = this.getView();
  var oModel = view.getModel();
  var viewModel = view.getModel("view");
  var viewData = viewModel.getData();
  // Read QuestionSet, populate into view model
  oModel.read("/QuestionSet", {
    filters: [
      new Filter("SurveyId", FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.SurveyId)
    ],
    success: function(oData) {
      viewData.Questions = oData.results;
      viewModel.setData(viewData);
      // Read CategorySet, get CategoryId & CategoryDesc, populate into view model
      return new Promise(function() {
        _.each(viewData.Questions, function(result, index) {
          var surveyModel = self.getView().getModel();
          surveyModel.read("/CategorySet", {
            filters: [
              new Filter("CategoryId", FilterOperator.EQ, result.CategoryId)
            ],
            success: function(oData) {
              viewData.Questions[index].CategoryId = oData.results[0].CategoryId;
              viewData.Questions[index].CategoryDesc = oData.results[0].CategoryDesc;
              viewModel.setData(viewData);
            },
            error: function(oError) {}
          });
        });
      });
    },
    error: function(oError) {}
  });
  // Read SurveySet, populate into view model
  oModel.read("/SurveySet", {
    filters: [
      new Filter("SurveyId", FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.SurveyId)
    ],
    success: function(oData) {
      viewData.SurveyName = oData.results[0].SurveyName;
      viewData.SurveyDesc = oData.results[0].SurveyDesc;
      viewData.ReportingFrom = oData.results[0].ReportingFrom;
      viewModel.setData(viewData);
    },
    error: function(oError) {}
  });
},
```

Image shows it gets `CategoryDesc` but not sorted by `CategoryDesc`:

[image: Image shows it gets CategoryDesc, but not sorted by CategoryDesc]

Image shows it sorted by a property from **QuestionSet**, not `CategorySet`:

[image: Image shows it sorted by a property from QuestionSet, not CategorySet]

Comment: How is the progress? Could you implement associations and navigation properties as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587773/5846045) below?

Answer (score 1):

What you might actually need are associations and navigation properties for the `QuestionSet` and `CategorySet` in your service metadata:

```xml
<EntityType Name="Question">
  <key>
    <PropertyRef Name="QuestionID"/>
  </key>
  <Property Name="QuestionID" ... />
  <Property Name="CategoryID" ... /> <!-- foreign key -->
  ...
  <NavigationProperty Name="ToCategory" ... />
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Category">
  <key>
    <PropertyRef Name="CategoryID"/>
  </key>
  <Property Name="CategoryID" ... />
  <Property Name="CategoryDesc" ... />
  ...
  <NavigationProperty Name="ToQuestions" ... />
</EntityType>

<Association Name="...">
  <End Role="Category" Multiplicity="1" ... /> <!-- a category contains many questions -->
  <End Role="Question" Multiplicity="*" ... /> <!-- a question belongs to one category -->
  <ReferentialConstraint>
    <Principal Role="Category">
      <PropertyRef Name="CategoryID"/>
    </Principal>
    <Dependent Role="Question">
      <PropertyRef Name="CategoryID"/> <!-- as a foreign key -->
    </Dependent>
  </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Then, you can easily sort by `CategoryDesc` by [expand](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#ExpandSystemQueryOption)ing the `QuestionSet` to `CategorySet` via navigation property.

```xml
<List
  items="{
    path: '/QuestionSet',
    parameters: {
     expand: 'ToCategory'
    },
    sorter: {
      path: 'ToCategory/CategoryDesc',
      descending: false,
      group: true
    }
  }"
  mode="SingleSelectMaster"
  selectionChange=".onQuestionSelect"
>
```

Here is a working example: [**https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/**](https://embed.plnkr.co/wAlrHB/?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,preview).

- It uses the [Northwind service](http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata) which has <kbd>Product</kbd><sup>n</sup>⎯⎯⎯<sup>1</sup><kbd>Category</kbd>.
- Declaratively say what is needed and how it should be sorted
- Not a single line of JS code was needed.